# Having to type computer name in credentials to login via RDP

Tags: networking, user-accounts, windows-8.1

I have several computers here running Windows 8.1 pro. Randomly on ONE of these PC's I have to type "computername\username" in the credentials for it to allow the credentials to work. All of my other computers allow a login with JUST the username. 
Any ideas if there is a gpedit, regedit, or something I am missing on this one PC that is making it need a computername name added to credentials?

Also to clarify I CAN remote into the other computers using the "computername\username", just randomly only one computer HAS to have this to even accept the credintials.

wow no idea how I forgot this but sorry forgot to clarify.. This is when trying to access the PC from another PC using RDP

thx Jace

Comment: Is it joined to a domain? A domain is very different from a hostname. It sounds to me like the one PC is on a different workgroup/homegroup.

Comment: No, all these computers here are just set to workgroup and are all part of the same homegroup. I just checked that one though to comfirm this.

Comment: Where are you entering the credentials? Are you connecting to Remote Desktop/shared folders from another PC or are you talking about the login/credential prompts on the computer itself?

Comment: via rdp using microsofts remote desktop connection. I haven't used the remote desktop/sharedfolders on this PC. thx

Comment: does it work when using `.\username`? Does it work using a different username?

Comment: actually.. yes ".\username" does work. I apologize that I am not familiar with what this does, but does this narrow it to a specific issue atleast? Also it doesn't matter the username it persists with any which are all admin users. thx